# memory allocation in structures

Tags: c, struct, malloc

My code uses two structures, block and layout (which is a collection of an arbitrary number of blocks).

```
struct block{
    char type;
    unsigned short int loc;
    unsigned short int size[2];
};
struct layout{
    unsigned short int no;
    struct block *blocks;
    short int **moves;
};
```

I am using this function to quickly initialize (and partly fill) the structure layout, based a set of blocks:

```
struct layout init_layout(int block_no, struct block *blocks){
    struct layout new_layout;
    int i, j;

    new_layout.no = (unsigned short int)block_no;
    // the following two lines cause an memory corruption error
    new_layout.blocks = (struct block *)malloc(block_no);
    new_layout.moves = (short int **)malloc(block_no);
    for(i = 0; i < block_no; i++){
        new_layout.blocks[i] = blocks[i];
        new_layout.moves[i] = (short int *)malloc(2);
        for(j = 0; j < 2; j++)
            new_layout.moves[i][j] = 0;
    }

    return new_layout;
}
```

So far, I do not see, that there is something wrong with it. However, when I call function like this

```
int main(int argc, char** argv){
    // just some arbitrary values for 10 blocks
    int size[2] = {2, 2};
    struct block *blocks = (struct block *)malloc(10);
    for(length = 0; length < 10; length++){
        blocks[length] = init_block('R', 1, size);
    }

    struct layout puzzle;
    puzzle = init_layout(10, blocks);
    return 0;
}
```

I end up with an memory corruption error, as marked by the comment in init_layout().
What do I miss in my implementation?

Comment: If your'r up to using a 2D array for `moves`, better use one, not a pointer to pointer.

Comment: so why not move the 0th dimension of `moves` into `block`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are allocating memory for anything, you need to analyze, closely -- "*What is it that I'm allocating memory for?*"

Below, you incorrectly assume a *cast* of an arbitrary number `block_no` will adequately size the memory needed for both `new_layout.blocks` and `new_layout.moves` -- it won't:

```
new_layout.blocks = (struct block *)malloc(block_no);
new_layout.moves = (short int **)malloc(block_no);
```

What you are allocating for `new_layout.blocks` is actually space for `struct block *blocks;` (a *pointer-to-struct-block*), while you can `malloc (block_no * sizeof (struct block));` to allocate space for `block_no` struct block, it is far better to allocate based upon what you are creating (i.e. space for an array `new_layout.blocks` (again a *pointer-to-struct-block*) which needs `block_no * sizeof *new_layout.blocks` bytes of memory to hold `block_no` of type `struct block`, e.g.:

```
new_layout.blocks = malloc(sizeof *new_layout.blocks * block_no);
new_layout.moves = malloc(sizeof *new_layout.moves * block_no);
```

(simply dereferencing the object you are allocating an array of, will accurate allow you to use `sizeof` to get the object (element) size for the array. (e.g. `sizeof *new_layout.blocks`) which you multiply by how many you need (e.g. `sizeof *new_layout.blocks * block_no)`

The same applies to:

```
    new_layout.moves[i] = malloc(**new_layout.moves * 2);
```

(*note:* here you are allocating for 2 shorts, so you will need to dereference you *pointer-to-pointer-to-short* twice to be allocating for `sizeof (short)`)

*See Also:* [**Do I cast the result of malloc?**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/995714) for thorough explanation.

Comment: also the same problem in main: malloc(10 * sizeof(struct block))

Comment: You should elaborate a bit more. Just providing some code will result in a question about a similar problem sooner or later.

Comment: You dropped `block_no`.

Comment: Thanks for your help, it seems I didn't properly understand the dynamic memory handling.

Comment: Sure, no problem, everybody has to learn it once. It was bewildering to me at one time also.

Answer (score 1):

For starters, this

```
  new_layout.blocks = (struct block *)malloc(block_no);
```

should be

```
  new_layout.blocks = malloc(block_no * sizeof *new_layout.blocks);
```

For the `moves` this is a bit more complicated.

Assuming `short int **moves;` should reference a certain number of `int[2]` the declaration is not optimal and better should be:

```
   short int (*moves)[2]; /* Define a pointer to 
                              an array with two elements of type short int. */
```

And allocation then should look like this:

```
  new_layout.moves = malloc(block_no * sizeof *new_layout.moves);
```

Finally initialisation goes like this:

```
  for(i = 0; i < block_no; i++){
    new_layout.blocks[i] = blocks[i];
    for(j = 0; j < sizeof new_layout.moves[0]/sizeof new_layout.moves[0][0]; j++)
        new_layout.moves[i][j] = 0;
  }
```

You might have noticed:

- No memory allocation in the loop any more.
- The magic number `2` only appears once.

:-)